# Error when compiling cryptominer

Tags: curl, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to compile a miner that is pretty old and may explain why it's not working, but I would really like to get it to work. It's kiyominer's cpu miner:

Git tree:   https://github.com/kiyominer/cpuminer

I'm following the build instructions in the README file and when I run the ./configure command I get the following output:

```
 checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-k1om-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-k1om-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for x86_64-k1om-linux-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for x86_64-k1om-linux-gcc... icc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether icc accepts -g... yes
checking for icc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether icc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of icc... gcc3
checking for icc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking how to run the C preprocessor... icc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking whether icc -std=gnu99 needs -traditional... no
checking dependency style of icc -std=gnu99... gcc3
checking for x86_64-k1om-linux-ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sys/endian.h usability... no
checking sys/endian.h presence... no
checking for sys/endian.h... no
checking sys/param.h usability... yes
checking sys/param.h presence... yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking syslog.h usability... yes
checking syslog.h presence... yes
checking for syslog.h... yes
checking for sys/sysctl.h... yes
checking whether be32dec is declared... no
checking whether le32dec is declared... no
checking whether be32enc is declared... no
checking whether le32enc is declared... no
checking for size_t... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for getopt_long... yes
checking for json_loads in -ljansson... no
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for gawk... (cached) mawk
checking for curl-config... /usr/bin/curl-config
checking for the version of libcurl... 7.35.0
checking for libcurl >= version 7.15.2... yes
checking whether libcurl is usable... no
configure: error: Missing required libcurl >= 7.15.2
```

and as you can see it finds libcurl but says it's unusable. Now in the README file it said one of the dependencies was libcurl found here "http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/ (built for mic)" and the "built for mic" I think is what's wrong. Is there a specific build of libcurl for mic? I simply downloaded using the command `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev`

Any Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I recently compiled the lastest version of kiyominer/cpuminer for k1om architecture.

You can download the RPM here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByMg9sbo5i4fYXBERE9hMEg4VWs/view?usp=sharing

Enjoy.